# Generating a google doc template from google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace

I am trying to create a google doc that is fed by a google sheet. Each row created in the sheet needs to generate a google doc in which the information in the row is inserted into the document template in the correct places. Any experience generating docs from individual rows in sheets and could assist with this?

Comment: You might get better answers, faster, if you include more information about what you already tried and if it's not working, some details about the errors or incorrect results you're seeing in Google Docs.

Comment: As suggest by @MatthewBakaitis there is a need fore more information in this post. You have already a good answer check if that works for you and if not, try to expand the post so you can explain further what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the solution you are looking for, but you may want to try this.

1. Make a table with google sheet like this one:

   [image: google sheet table example]
2. create a new document within google drive, and type the variables with double brackets like this: {{name}}

   [image: document example]
3. Go to the add-ons market in g suite market place, and search for **document studio**.

   With it, you can generate files with custom data from a google sheet.
   (it has a free trial with limit to 20 document a month per user if I remember correctly).
4. After you install it, access your google sheet again and open the add on. It will look like this:

   [image: document studio example]
5. Choose your google doc, and the add-on will automatically identify the variables you listed.

You can then select the file output type (PDF, WORD etc..). The add-on can send the file via email if needed as well.